# Doctrine/Symfony2 : Exception when trying to persist multiple element

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I tried to upload multiples photos to a product but it does not work
this Exception is :

**Exception:**

> Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association ...\Entity\Product#photos, but expecting ....\Entity\Photos
>   500 Internal Server Error - ORMException

I have 2 Entities :

**Product :**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photos", mappedBy="product")
 */
private $photos;
```

**Photos :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="photos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $product;
```

**and in my Controller :**

```
......

$files = $form->get('photos')->getData(); // I use Transformer to transform data to Photos Entity
foreach($files as $list){
   foreach($list as $item){
        $product->addPhoto($item);
   }
}

$em->persist($product);
$eù->flush();
```

**Stack Trace (Plain Text):**

> [1] Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association ..\Entity\Product#photos, but expecting Portfolio\Backend\BackendBundle\Entity\Photos
>       at n/a
>           in C:..\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 791

```
at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeAssociationChanges(array('fieldName' => 'photos', 'mappedBy' => 'product', 'targetEntity' => '..\Entity\Photos', 'cascade' => array(), 'orphanRemoval' => false, 'fetch' => '2', 'type' => '4', 'inversedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => false, 'sourceEntity' => '..\Entity\Product', 'isCascadeRemove' => false, 'isCascadePersist' => false, 'isCascadeRefresh' => false, 'isCascadeMerge' => false, 'isCascadeDetach' => false), object(PersistentCollection))
    in C:\..\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 687

at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeChangeSet(object(ClassMetadata), object(Product))
    in C:\..\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 404

at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeScheduleInsertsChangeSets()
    in C:\..\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 711

at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeChangeSets()
    in C:\..\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 297

at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit(null)
    in C:\..\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php line 340

at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush()
    in C:\..\Controller\ProductController.php line 516

at ..\Controller\PostsController->createAction(object(Request))
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProductController), 'createAction'), array(object(Request)))
    in C:\..\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 3094

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in C:\..\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 3056

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in C:\..\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 3207

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in C:\..\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2429

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in C:\..\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

---

> object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[509]   private
>   'elements' => 
>       array (size=2)
>         'file' => 
>           object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[603]
>             private 'elements' => 
>               array (size=1)
>                 ...
>         0 => 
>           object(..\Entity\Medias)[740]
>             private 'id' => null
>             private 'file' => 
>               object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[13]
>                 ...
>             private 'product' => null

You have an idea for this exception?

Comment: can you post the full text of the exception that you're getting?

Comment: @xocasdashdash I edited my question

Comment: After checking your edited answer you should double check your mapping, it can get somewhat complicated and you might need to flush twice (although you shouldn't)
This: ```'isCascadePersist' => false``` is why I suspect this to be the problem

Comment: @xocasdashdash I do not understand why in my property photos i have 2 attributes file type ArrayCollection and Photos Object

Answer (score 0):

First you should add all required attributes for [@JoinColumn](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="photos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $product;
```

Then check your script again.